# bool property to Func<bool> conversion

Tags: c#, .net

I have `boolean` property in my class.
I want to pass it as parameter to some function that expects Func.
Is there any way to make the conversion ? or I should just make a function that returns `bool` instead of property ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the function really expects a `Func<bool>` (a function that takes no parameters and return a `bool`), you can do it like this:

```
SomeFunction( () => myClass.BoolProperty);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a lambda:

FuncToCall(() => myObject.MyBoolProperty);

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
SomeFunction(()=>SomeBool);
```

where SomeBool it a boolean property of your class.

Answer (score 0):

To pass your property in a func metod

```
Method1(c=> MyProperty);
```

And the func / property looks like this

```
public bool MyProperty
{
   get { return true; }
}

public void Method1(Func<bool, bool> func)
{ 
}
```

And if the function expects a func that only returns a bool like this:

```
public void Method1(Func<bool> func)
{ 
}
```

this is the way to call it

```
Method1(()=> MyProperty);
```